# Make TH equals to 3 columns in HTML

Tags: html

[image]Hello, I want to make ACTIONS equal to three columns

As shown in image, I want ACTIONS in center of Detail Update Delete

Please help.

Comment: Please show your HTML-Code.

Comment: you can use colspan="3"  in the th

Comment: thanks its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>AGE</th>
    <th colspan="3">ACTIONS</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Salman Mushtaq</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td><a href="#">Detail</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Update</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Muhanmmad Awais</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td><a href="#">Detail</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Update</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Imran Hassan</td>
    <td>38</td>
    <td><a href="#">Detail</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Update</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Muhammad Asad</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td><a href="#">Detail</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Update</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

Try to search about `colspan` and `rowspan`

Answer (score 1):

Use `colspan` attribute in `TH` tag (ie. `colspan="3"`)

```
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th colspan="3">Action (spanned 3 cols)</th>                        
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>action 1</td>
                    <td>Action 2</td>
                    <td>Action 3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```